# Recursively checking lists of list in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to calculate every 2 grades' (list's each element) averages in a recursive way.

```
list = [['2.5', '45'], ['59', '99']]
```

EDITED:

I changed my algorithm and my code is:

```
def a(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return 0
    else:
        return lst[0] / 2 + a(lst[1:2])


lst = [9.600000000000001, 37.2, 35.6, 34.4]
a(lst)
```

It calculates averages perfectly for first 2 elements of the list. I'm wondering how to generate it for all elements.

Comment: What was your trial approach?

Comment: first go in the first element of the list .. firstly base case is an empty list.. then if not empty list return element's last element + function[:1]

Comment: @IronFist is it right?

Comment: Would you explain more? There is no need for recursive way if you only want to calculate mentioned list. unless you look for calculating n-level nested list.

Comment: When someone asks what you have tried already, what they mean is to post the code you have written so far, specifically the smallest part of the code needed to see what you tried, so people can read and respond to it.

Comment: Perfect - just a note though, in the case of Python, indentation is critical, since it actually defines the code structure. You hadn't indented the contents of your `a()` method, so the syntax was not valid. I have edited to fix that in this case, but in the future, you may want to review the edit preview before saving changes, to check for things such as indentation and other formatting to clean up.

Comment: @B.Joelene .. What are you trying to do here exactly?...because after your edit, it seems now you have a flat list of integers instead of list of lists of strings?...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with list comprehension:

```
   >>> lst=[['2.5', '45'], ['59', '99']]
   >> avg = [sum(map(float, x))/len(x) for x in lst]
   [23.75, 79.0]
```

So, what's happening in the above expression, is for every sub-list `x` of `lst` we are summing the `float` value of every element of this sub-list `x` and then diving by its length `len`, to get the average

**Note:**

Avoid naming your variables with Python Built-in names, to not shadow them during your script

Answer (score 0):

example

```
lst=[['2.5', '45'], ['59', '99']]
averages=[(float(x)+float(y))/2 for x,y in lst]
print(averages)
```